# Official announcement about FB sharer.php script

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

There's a lot of chatter everywhere about Facebook sharer.php script being deprecated, but no official word about it from Facebook. They are not documenting this sharing method on their site, but it's still functional and being used by many large websites (YouTube, NY Times, Huffpo and many more).

The problem with the new sharing API (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) is that it forces you to open a Facebook app for each site you are developing, even for a simple general site share, which seems a bit odd.

Can anyone help me find official word from Facebook about this? is it safe to keep using sharer.php? are there any differences between the 2 sharing methods? I found a blog post saying that posts shared by sharer.php are only appearing on your wall and does not appear on your newsfeed, but I suspect that this is only a user's setting issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `sharer.php` endpoint was officially deprecated sometime in 2011. All of the docs announcing this have been removed from the Facebook documentation. This isn't the best situation for new developers because many older tutorials still show this as a proper path.

The only official word I could find is in this bug report from April 2012: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/252983554810810/

It is not safe to keep using `sharer.php`. Even if it works today, it may stop working at any time.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily true. The [share bookmarklet](https://www.facebook.com/share_options.php) still uses `sharer.php`; I find it hard to imagine they'd shut that off without some sort of advanced warning.

Comment: There was advance warning. Evidence of the warning still exists. See this [Quora thread from January 2011](http://www.quora.com/Will-Facebook-get-rid-of-sharer-php-soon). Facebook has scrubbed all reference to this endpoint from their official documentation. Try Googling `site:developers.facebook.com sharer.php` other than a few bug reports, nothing.

Comment: That share bookmarklet page seems to be an orphan as well. I don't see any official link to that page from Facebook anymore.

Comment: That Quora thread has nothing definite or official (i.e. someone from Facebook answered). And the fact that it's almost two years old should mean something too. If Facebook was serious about deprecating it (read: disabling it completely) I think they'd post an official warning on the [developer blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/). All that said, migrating from `sharer.php` isn't an awful idea, but I don't think it's as critical as "It's not safe to keep using `sharer.php`".

Comment: There used to be an official announcement. I've referenced it on SO as late as this summer. It's all gone now. All those pages just redirect to the like button. I agree that there should be *something* to explain its absence, especially with the amount of tutorials that still reference it. Maybe it's all a cover-up: It was `sharer.php` that killed MySpace, and Zuck is hiding it in his basement to avoid prosecution.

Comment: It seems to be (kind of) back: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share/ 
At least it doesn't mention being deprecated.